# Increase the "precision" of a heatmap

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

Using `seaborn` i am generating heatmaps for various series of a DataFrame.

The main code that I use is the following:

```
def plot_heatmap(data, cmap, x_label, y_label, y_ticks = None):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    heatmap = sns.heatmap([data], robust=True,cmap=cmap, annot=False, cbar_kws={"label": "Value"}, ax=ax)

    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
    if y_ticks:
        heatmap.set_yticklabels([y_ticks])

    plt.show()
```

And it's invoked per case that I have (for each Pandas.Series). My issue is that the generated result looks like this:

[image]

But the thing is, that this looks somewhat deceiving. I generated the following random dataset for this plot: [gist for dataset](https://gist.github.com/NikosDelijohn/4d08d103d31a5768f1d91226a6b4063f).

The number of zeroes as you see is 1. But someone, observing this plot would think otherwise.

So, how could I improve this plot to make it more accurate? I tried various cmaps like:

```
    cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True) 
    cmap2 = sns.diverging_palette(250, 0, sep=1, n=256, as_cmap=True)
    cmap3 = 'gist_rainbow'
    ...
```

But I didn't quite get the desired result. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a massive range of scales. You can try plotting a logarithm of the data:

`plot_heatmap(np.log10(df.data), cmap="plasma", x_label="asdf", y_label="asdf")`

[image]

You can bin your data and plot the bins/categories. E.g. values between 0 and 10 are one colour, values larger than 1e20 are another. You can define the bins in any way that suits your dataset or what you want to show. In the first example below I create 20 equally spaced bins in `log10` space.

```
bins = np.logspace(np.log10(0.1), np.log10(df["data"].max()), 20)
labels = np.arange(1, len(bins))

df["binned"] = pd.cut(df["data"], bins=bins, labels=labels)

plot_heatmap(df["binned"], cmap="magma", x_label="asdf", y_label="asdf")
```

[image]

And here I manually define values for the bins:

```
bins = [-1, 100, 1e6, 1e9, df["data"].max()]
labels = np.arange(1, len(bins))

df["binned"] = pd.cut(df["data"], bins=bins, labels=labels)

plot_heatmap(df["binned"], cmap="magma", x_label="asdf", y_label="asdf")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the second part of your answer regarding the bins?

Comment: @ex1led Added another example, hope that's useful. You can define the bins to show whatever you want to show, depending on your data and what values you're interested/not interested in. NB, the colorbar in this case shows your defined categories (bins), and is no longer representative of actual values.

Comment: Thanks for that!! Given that my data are massive and have a really high standard deviation, the binning idea seems great. So practically I could do some descriptive statistics, and create bins for all values in the Q1, Q2 (median), and Q3, or something similar.

Comment: After some attempts to manually do the binning i tried using as bins the following `bins = [ df.min(), (df.min()+q1)/2, q1, (q1+q2)/2, q2, (q2+q3)/2, q3, df.max()]` for my samples. In the result binning in some cases i had `NaN` values appearing instead of bins which were ploted as whitespace in the heatmap. So i changed bins to `bins = [ -np.inf, df.min(), (df.min()+q1)/2, q1, (q1+q2)/2, q2, (q2+q3)/2, q3, df.max(), np.inf]` and that resolved my problem.  Is such an approach valid?

Comment: @ex1led, your changed `bins` will have one bin covering values between `-np.inf` and `df.min()`. This bin will have only one value in it: `df.min()`. Same for the other end of the bin values. I'd stick with your first approach, but replace `df.min()` with `-np.inf`, or with `df.min() - 1`: `bins = [-np.inf, (df.min()+q1)/2, q1, (q1+q2)/2, q2, (q2+q3)/2, q3, df.max()]`